# I have added git clone in my docker file. Image is built successfully

Tags: docker, dockerfile, clone, docker-image

but unable to find my cloned source code in image .on local machine clone is workking but not for docker conatiner.
RUN git clone https://h..../public.git

### Successfully built image id

FROM ubuntu

MAINTAINER Luke Crooks "luke@pumalo.org"

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y apache2 && apt-get clean

RUN apt-get install -y git

RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/

RUN touch /root/.ssh/id_rsa

EXPOSE 8080/tcp

RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN ssh-keyscan -T 60 bitbucket.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN git clone -b newbr https://haseeb@bitbucket.org/haseeb/public.git

WORKDIR  /var/lib/docker/overlay2/work

Comment: First of all it will be a container in which you should try to get the code not image, and it depends on the wordir in which you have cloned the code. paste your dockerfile here.

Comment: I’d expect the code to be in `/public` inside the image.  (Putting a `/var/lib/docker` path in your Dockerfile looks a little unusual.). You also might find it easier to run `git clone` from the host before you build the image.

Comment: tried git clone from host machine it showmed me the repo cloned using url

Answer (score 0):

try to update the docker file like the below snippet and build again

```
FROM ubuntu

MAINTAINER Luke Crooks "luke@pumalo.org"

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y apache2 && apt-get clean

RUN apt-get install -y git

RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/

RUN touch /root/.ssh/id_rsa

EXPOSE 8080/tcp

RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN ssh-keyscan -T 60 bitbucket.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN makdir -p /var/lib/docker/overlay2/work
WORKDIR /var/lib/docker/overlay2/work
RUN git clone -b newbr https://haseeb@bitbucket.org/haseeb/public.git
```

The cloned repo should be in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/work`